# How to create a thread in Android NDK?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-ndk

Can anyone tell me how to create a thread in Android NDK? I'm porting some C++ code from Win32 to Android, I don't know what's the NDK API corresponding to Win32 API AfxBeginThread(). Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Android NDK (partially) support POSIX thread, so you can use [pthread_create](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html).